# how to open the partial view as popup on jqgrid edit/add/delete option

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, jqgrid

When i click the add/edit button it should show the partial view form as modal popup.

```
 $('#list').jqGrid({  
       caption: "Employee Details",  
       url: '/Employee/GetEmployee/',  
       datatype: "json",  
       contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",  
       mtype: 'GET',  
       colNames: ['Address', 'City', 'Id', 'Name'],  
       colModel: [  
             { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 150 },  
             { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 150 },  
             { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 150 },  
             { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150 }  
       ],  
       rowNum: 10,  
       loadonce: true  

   });  

   jQuery("#list").jqGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false});
```

how can i achieve this..any help really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid works as JavaScript library and it can't use any partial views. If you want to show edit/add/delete buttons then you should replace the line

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false});
```

to

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager');
```

and to add `editable: true` property in the columns of `colModel`, which you want allow the user to edit. You have to use `pager: '#pager'` option in jqGrid too. You have to include empty div `<div id="pager"></div>` in HTML markup of the page additionally. To be exactly the answer on your question depend on the version of jqGrid, which you use and the fork of jqGrid. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop, allows to use `pager: true` option of jqGrid and to skip `'#pager'` parameter of `navGrid` method. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/SMALL-improvements-in-the-usage-of-jqGrid#one-dont-need-to-create-div-idpagerdiv) for more information.

Additionally you can remove unneeded `index` properties and to remove `width: 150` property too, because 150 is the default value of `width` property. To be able to edit the data, you will have to add `editurl` parameter with the URL of MVC action, which should be called on editing.